# A query about matrices over a field $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{p}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Consider the ring of all $2\times 2$ matrices $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{p}})$.
Then for non zero elements $a$ and $b$, is the number of distinct matrices  with  determinant equal to $a$ and number of matrices with determinant equal to $b$ the same?. Further is the number of matrices with determinant $1$ greater than number of matrices with determinant $0$?.

My thinking:-
I know that the number of units in $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{p}})$ is $(p^{2}-1)(p^{2}-p)$and they form a group under multiplication(I just have to find two linearly independent non zero rows).
So if a be non zero. Then the number of matrices with determinant $a$ should be equal to the number of matrix with determinant $b$ as both a and b are generators of the field and shouldn't really be different. However I am having trouble to actually formally prove this or disprove this.
Also for the subsidiary question...I can find the number of matrices with determinant $0$ are just $p^{4}-(p^{2}-1)(p^{2}-p)$. But for $p=2$ the number of elements with determinant $1$ is $6$ and number of matrix with determinant $0$ is therefore $10$.Hence the 2nd proposiotion is wrong for p=2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, nice question, I think this has been asked before but the usual proof is to consider what happens when you multiply the top row by each non-zero constant, this "relation" splits all of the non-singular matrices into classes with one of each determinant, this generalizes to every size and every finite field :)

Comment: Ah. I see...so is the relation $A\rho B$ iff $det(A)=det(B)$ an equivalence relation for non zero singular A and B ?

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee You know the definition of an equivalence relation, right?  You tell us.

Comment: No the equivalence relation was: The matrices coincide in every row except the top one, and the top row of the first matrix is a non-zero multiple of the top row of the other one.

Comment: Consider reading this question ! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144469/is-there-any-way-to-find-the-number-of-matrices-with-a-given-determinant-in-gl

Comment: @yorch thanks a lot!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion on the number matrices with a particular $\det$ is indeed true. It follows from the fact that cosets of a normal subgroup partition a group into sets of equal size.

If $D: GL_{2} \to \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is the determinant map then $D$ is a homomorphism and $D^{-1}\{a\} = A \cdot \ker(D) = A \cdot D^{-1}\{1\}$ where $A$ is any matrix such that $\det(A) = a$.

Since $A$ is invertible in this case, the map $A:D^{-1}\{1\} \to D^{-1}\{a\}$ is a bijection.

As for your second claim about $p=2$, it is indeed incorrect.

Comment: Absolutely perfect

Comment: Also by this I can say that the number of matrices with determinant $a$ where $a$ is non zero is just $\frac{(p^{2}-1)(p^{2}-p)}{\text{number of units}}=\frac{(p^{2}-1)(p^{2}-p)}{p-1}$ .

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This question was bothering me since yesterday as I was failing to establish some sort of proof. I could only derive non general results for particular $p$.

Comment: If you want some drama, you can try calculating the number of units in $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2})$ and then maybe $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_{p^k})$

Comment: I'll get on it. I'll try this for the entire tomorrow.